# How can I move each folder on my desktop iteratively with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an  AppleScript that iterates through the folders in my Desktop folder and moves them to a subfolder called "destination". (I need to iterate through the Desktop folders instead of moving them all at once because I want each folder to be moved or not moved based on a randomly generated number).

My code:

```
set desktopFolders to (path to desktop as text)
set destinationFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "destination"

    tell application "System Events"
        set subFolders to (get every disk item of folder desktopFolders)
        repeat with eachFolder in subFolders
            move eachFolder to destinationFolder
        end repeat
    end tell
```

The script works if I try to move the entire `subFolders` variable into `destinationFolder`, and it doesn't throw an error from trying to iterate through `eachFolder` in `subFolders`. However, when I try to move `eachFolder` into `destinationFolder`, I get the following error:

`System Events got an error: NSArgumentsWrongScriptError`

Any reason the `eachFolder` variable isn't able to be moved in this way? Is there a better way to iterate through the folders in my Desktop folder, such that I can move each one of them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `desktopFolders` to: `desktopFolder`

- Note there is no `s` on the end, as the **Desktop** *folder* is singular not plural.

Change `disk item` in:

```
set subFolders to (get every disk item of folder desktopFolder)
```

To: `folder`

Also add:

```
whose name is not "destination"
```

To the end of:

```
get every folder of folder desktopFolder
```

Example:

```
set subFolders to (get every folder of folder desktopFolder whose name is not "destination")
```

You do not want to try moving the `destination` *folder* into itself.

Sans making `desktopFolders` singular, these other changes allow the rest of the *code* to work without error while testing under **macOS High Sierra**.

Comment: Solved! The issue was trying to move destination into itself. Thank you!